# Is there a signal/slot connection in QT to change colors based on values changing

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am trying to change some formatting in QT based on some values changing.  I am using some epicsQT widgets which read some values off instruments (humidity is one example).  I want the color of a button to change (and flash, if possible) to change if the value exceeds some limit (let's say 85 percent for humidity).

Is there a signal/slot combination to use?  I've tried the update(), and tried to model the painterEvent that's covered in the analogClock [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html).  But I don't think this is an "event."  Aren't events different than signals?

For testing, I've been trying with just a simple spinBox, and a qanalogSlider to try to get the MainWindow to change color.  I just want the color to change (and possibly flash) if the value goes over something arbitrary (say greater than 5).

Comment: As you mentioned in the other question: you have to "*Stop beeing afraid of c++*" and write your c++ slot, to achieve that. In this example: 1. create a public slot in your *.h* and implement it in the *.cpp* file. The implementation can change the color of spinbox. 2. Connect the `valueChanged` signal of the spinbox either using `QObject::connect` in the codebehind or using the "Signal&Slot Editor" of the Designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own signals and slots  so you can do something like:

```
private slots:
    void SlotThatFormat();
signals:
    void mySignal();
```

and then use `emit(mySignal());` and a `connect(A, SIGNAL(mySignal()),B, SLOT(SlotThatFormat()));`

As you can create them, you can decide what type of arguments they use and what they do. So if you, for example want to use a bool as an argument and change the color you could do something like:

```
private slots:
  void mySlot(bool value);
signals:
  void mySignal(bool value); // remember that both slot and signal need to use the same type of argument

private:
  bool boolVar;
```

Then in cpp constructor or where you want:

```
connect(A, SIGNAL(mySignal(bool)), B, SLOT(mySlot(bool)));
```

and when you want to activate it you need to emit the signal like:

```
emit(mySignal(boolVar);
```

Finally in cpp you can do what you want with your slot which is something like a function:

```
void YourWindow::mySlot(bool value)
{
   //Here code that changes what you need
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen examples on how to make general slots and signals.  But I still cannot figure out how to make (or use) a slot that changes the color of a widget.

Comment: What type of functions or commands take a boolean and change the colors?  I'm really new to QT and am having a hard time figuring out simple stuff like this.

Comment: @thestarsatnight I have edited it with a bigger explanation and a example, maybe this helps you understand how it works